# Linear Layout - fixed height children are wrongly placed

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I'm placing 3 `TextView` in a `LinearLayout` and want them to be equaly distributed AND to have a fixed height. The combination of `layout_weight` and a fixed `layout_height` should make sure, that all 3 views are always shown in one line and are always of equal height. But they aren't.

Can someone explain where the problem lies? I can't find it...

Here's my `LinearLayout` with it's children:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMuted"
        android:text="@string/color_palette_muted"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMutedLight"
        android:text="@string/color_palette_muted_light"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMutedDark"
        android:text="@string/color_palette_muted_dark"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set `android:layout_gravity="center"` in all the TextView's as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMuted"
        android:text="@string/color_palette_muted"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMutedLight"
        android:text="@string/color_palette_muted_light"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMutedDark"
        android:text="@string/color_palette_muted_dark"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That helps, but does not explain why fixed height children with evenly distributed weights are not drawn in one line. Any ideas? I'm sure I've used it like above about 50 times already and it always worked...

Comment: Still I did not think about trying this, I helps, thanks

Comment: Welcome, the reason behind using this might be the content. As the content increases, the layout starts looking unorganised.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMuted"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="MUTED"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMutedLight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="MUTED-HELL"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMutedDark"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="MUTED-DUNKEL"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I can't use `android:weightSum="3"` because I may hide some views and only one or two items will be visible..

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.ncrypted.demoapplications.Main2Activity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMuted"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#F00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="color1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#F00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="color1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#F00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="color1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put This line in every text view `android:singleLine="true"`    This will wrap your text in single line

> Can someone explain where the problem lies? I can't find it...

The problem is your Fixed Hight 64dp actully you told to view that view should expand up to 64 dp in center focused text
but when  text is large than your textview text will cut from all side 
There are Three option for this

**1**.make textview hight "**WrapContent**" but in this case all textview with different hight as text length

**2**.Make text single line **android:singleLine="true"** like Muted-Dun...   like this basically it show your text in single line

**3**. set  **android:layout_gravity="center"** but in this case if your text length is large than your text is cut

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute `android:weightSum="3"` and `android:gravity="center"` to your `LinearLayout`.

**Here is the working code:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMuted"
        android:text="Muted"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#958F81">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMutedLight"
        android:text="Muted - Hell"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#A4A38E">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMutedDark"
        android:text="Mmuted - Dunkel"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#686868">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]